# ESLINT_ERROR: Parsing error: Identifier directly after number Error during conversion of javascript button to Lighrning

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

### I have a Salesforce onClick Javascript button that I am trying to convert to Lightning using the Transition utility. When I click Convert on this button, I get the following error: (Even though it says Deployment component, this occurs during conversion itself).

> Something went wrong with the deployment. Component:
>   LCC_Create_Invoice_OpportunityController. Problem: ESLINT_ERROR:
>   {c:LCC_Create_Invoice_Opportunity - CONTROLLER} line:col [4:12] -->
>   Parsing error: Identifier directly after number.

My generated code is as follows:

```
<aura:component extends="c:LCC_GenericLightningComponent" >
    <aura:attribute name="partiallyConfirm" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:set attribute="isAdditionalObject" value="false"></aura:set>

    <div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.partiallyConfirm}">
                <div class="slds-m-bottom_x-large">
                    <span><lightning:icon iconName="utility:warning" size="small"/></span><span class="slds-m-left_xx-small">This Js Button has been partially migrated. Contact with your System Administrator to review the functionality.</span>
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
            <p>'Go to the Invoice Record ?'</p>
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.yesResponse}" label="Yes" />
            <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.noResponse}" label="No"/>
        </footer>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

And the Controller is thus:

```
({

    yesResponse : function(component, event, helper) {
        123YesResponse123

        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    },

    noResponse : function(component, event, helper) {
        123NoResponse123

        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
})
```

-
What gives? Happy to provide any other information. TIA.
P.S. I have also tried redesigning it using some different Lightning constructs e.g. flow, action etc., but none has worked because there are some basic issues in the schema. Thus, code conversion seems like the last resort.

Comment: What is “ 123YesResponse123”? That’s not valid JS

Comment: Yes definitely. This is a "generated" Lightning code by the javascript button converter made available by Salesforce. In addition, there is apparently a controller (possibly Apex, I am guessing) and the generated apex code is not made available. Possibly someone who is familiar with this conversion process can clarify.

Comment: In the code you posted, there is no reference to any apex. And It does look like that `123` stuff is preventing you from saving the component... Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Thank you. I will remove that line and see how it proceeds. For now, thanks everyone!! If there is any further help needed, then I'll continue.